# Best framework for hybrid app for instant messenger

Tags: html, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I wonna start to develop an hybrid app for an application which has a instant messages as core, besides some other realtime feature. 
I was having a look to Cordova and ionic. Are these technology the right election? 
Is there any module or instant messages project which I can use instead to write a new one?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at 
``[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) from google
They even have a fully working chat application with [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firechat) 
working demo [demo](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/)

Con:- Your app is tied to google firebase infrastructure